# iOS7:editable textfield cells in tableview is not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios7

```
Editable textfield cells Tableview is causing problem on keyboard tab button everytime it is calling textfieldshouldbeginediting even if i am in first textfield it is not going to nextfield.
```

It is going to last textfield and if popover is availabe it will crash.How can i fix this so that if enter tab then it has to resign current responder in textfielddidendediting and it should not go to textfieldshouldbegin editing.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  PickerViewController *selectOperatorController;
  NSLog(@"tag %d",textField.tag);
  return NO;
}
I also declared textfield delegates like didendediting and shouldendediting
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  activeField = nil;
  if (self.chooseOperatorController) {
     [self.chooseOperatorController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  }
  return YES;
}   
This is not as issue in iOS 6.But it is in iOS 7.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textfieldshouldbegin editing will not allow desktop keyboard tab button input,it cannot judge to move between the textfields.If we add textfielddidbeginediting we can move the controls,eventhough we have two methods we can move by using keyboard tab.So textfielddidbeginediting is mandatory if we want to move bewtween available textfields.